# Set Line chart's start value to the lowest in an array

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm using `Line` chart from `'react-chartjs-2'`

```
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
```

I have particular dataset, which is the array of numbers. Negative and positive.

[image]

This is my `options` and `dataset` configurations for the charts:

dataset:

```
const chartData = {
      labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Chart',
        data: data,
        backgroundColor: 'linear-gradient(to right, #20f08b, #07dfb1)',
        borderColor: '#05deb3'
      }]
    }
```

options:

```
const options = {
  elements: {
    line: { tension: 0 },
    point: { radius: 0 }
  },
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      display: false,
      gridLines: { display: false },
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        min: getMinValue(data),
        max: getMaxValue(data),
        suggestedMin: getMinValue(data),
        suggestedMax: getMaxValue(data),
      }
    }],
    xAxes: [{
      display: false,
      gridLines: { display: false }
    }],
  },
  legend: { display: false },
  angleLines: { display: false },
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  animation: { duration: 0 }
}
```

The problem is that my chart fall goes under the mark 0. But I want it to start from the lowest value in my array. I have the following in my options:

```
 ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        min: getMinValue(data),
        max: getMaxValue(data),
        suggestedMin: getMinValue(data),
        suggestedMax: getMaxValue(data),
      }
```

but it doesn't work. Also if I set min value to 0 and max to the highest value in my array I have the following result:

```
ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            min: 0,
            max: getMaxValue(data),
            suggestedMin: 0,
            suggestedMax: getMaxValue(data),
          }
```

[image]

So I don't event see the values under 0.

Who knows how to fix this?

Comment: How is your `data` variable structured?

Comment: @bntzio, `["32", "25", "15", "13", "0", "-25", "24", "32", "35", "2.89"]`